# what does it mean by "reading sth to memory" and "reading sth into memory"

Tags: memory, terminology, semantics

All I know about the `read` & `write` operations is that the `read` operation reads data from somewhere & the `write` operation store data to memory. With that being said, `read sth from memory` and `write sth to memory` are totally understandable but `read sth into memory` as well as `read sth to memory` makes no sense to me.

Comment: "sth" is an English-language **written** abbreviation (not verbal) for "something", so "read sth from memory" means "read something from memory". (That said, I personally see non-native English speakers using "sth" far more frequently than native speakers)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19841/what-is-meant-by-sth

Comment: "read sth into memory" is likely a typo for "write sth [something] into memory"

Comment: @Dai I do get what `sth` means. Btw, thank you for clarifying the "read sth into memory" phrase for me. I've been searching for the meaning of the phrase for a while but can't get any answer. It's also weird that the typo is so widely used in online articles, questions on stackoverflow, it even appears in books making we very confusing

Comment: Well, _writing_ something to memory still requires the computer to conceptually *read* it from somewhere first - which could be a register, IO address, or another memory location.

Comment: @HunqVux Some context would help, especially since "*read*" and "*write*" have many uses unrelated to memory. Most likely, "*read sth into memory*" is just shorthand for "*read sth from elsewhere and write it to memory*". For example, "*read the next keyboard event [and save it to the input queue] into memory*".

Comment: @Dai oh, I didn't consider the reading & write processes in the first place. Thank you for explaining

Comment: @dxiv I finally get it, Thank you for the great explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a CPU's perspective, `read sth into memory` or `read sth to memory` generally means loading data from disk(or other much slower devices) to memory.

Comment: [Dai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/159145/dai)'s answer makes more sense to me, at least in my context. I had done some searches for the phrases. Although I found no proper answer, it seems that what people really wanna do when they `read sth into memory` is actually `write sth into memory`.

Comment: [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420/dxiv)'s answer is great too